# histogram based on counts of one variable with intervals of numerical variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a histogram of the counts where dengue=1 and the x-axis being the age.cut variable.

```
 dengue age  sex    net sector ageHalf  age.cut
1   0   16  female  no  sector1 0      (15,20]
2   0   33  male    no  sector1 0      (30,35]
3   0   1   male    no  sector1 0      [0,5]
4   0   35  male    no  sector1 0      (30,35]
5   0   6   male    no  sector1 0      (5,10]
6   0   27  female  no  sector2 0      (25,30]
7   0   6   male    no  sector2 0      (5,10]
```

Being new to r, I'm not quite sure how to get the histogram to plot the correct information. I have the age variable cut into intervals of 5.

I have created a data frame that contains only the dengue=1 and age.cut intervals but don't know where to even start after that.

```
df<-dengue[index, c(1,7)]
```

Basically I just want to get a histogram that gives the total counts in each interval and places them in a bar chart--to look at the distribution.

Thanks!

Connor

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the cuts manually, can't you use hist:

```
hh = hist(df[,"age"], breaks=seq(5,50,by=5))
```

check hh afterwards. And to filter only dengue == 1 - probably filter from the dplyr package:

```
df1 = dplyr::filter(df, dengue == 1)
```